# how to update state when state is object that contains array of objects in React 17

Tags: react-hooks

I have a form that collects demographic information for one adult and also for each child (minor) that will accompany the adult. Example of data for one minor: {firstName: "Jimmy", lastName: "Smith"}).

I can use  setMinors((prevArray) => [...prevArray, data]) to update the minors state as the user adds, edits and possibly deletes minors.

On form submit, I want to setWaiver() with the collection of objects from the minors state at that time, but I cannot determine the correct way to do this.

const[minors, setMinors] = useState([]);

const[waiver, setWaiver] = useState({ firstName : "", lastName : "", email : "", minors: [] });

If you have insight into how to accomplish updating the waiver state to include the objects from the minors state, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update minors in waiver that code will help you

```js
const[minors, setMinors] = useState([]);

const[waiver, setWaiver] = useState({ firstName : "", lastName : "", email : "", minors: [] });

const updateMinors=(newMinors)=>{
  setWaiver((prevWaiver)=>({...prevWaiver, minors : newMinors}));
}
```